# JavaScript OOP - class methods (signatures and conventions)

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

Let's say I'm building a simple MVC JavaScript visualization.

A controller for a specific visualization view can look something like this:

```
Controller {

 model
 year
 width
 height
 xScale
 yScale

 render() {
    this.year = this.model.get("year")
    this.width = this.model.get("width")
    updateScales();

    draw A, B, C
 }

 updateScales() {
   this.xScale = this.width ...
 }

}
```

As you can see, each time the Controller's render method is invoked, it sets some attributes and updates the "derived scale attributes".

I have two questions regarding this code:

1) Is it a bad practice to have the class methods work directly on class attributes? Should they rather return a value and have a signature?

2) Suppose I'd like to optimize this code so that updateScales are only called when either width or height are changed. What is a good - and fairly generic way - of handling such model attribute change related logic?

Comment: are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: What wheel? :) I'm curious about what the pros and cons are of returning a value and setting the signature explicitly in this case.

Comment: 1) Depends ;). 2) As you have already set the backbone.js framework tag for your question, check [its `Model` documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model) and look for "change" event handling.

Answer (score 0):

1) in general it is a good practice to have access to properties by means of *set* and *get* methods. This way you can easily implement additional operations which could be done when modifying a property.
2) as [Julian D. said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170132/julian-d), you can handle the updatescale with the 'change' event of backbone.js

It is not clear in your post, however, if you are actually using backbone.js or not.